# intransitive usage of "vorlegen"

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, verb-usage

In the minutes of an official committee, I have found the following sentence:
*"Zum Zeitpunkt des letzten Komitees lagen noch keine aktuellen Werte für die Prognosen der Bank vor."*

I am surprise by this usage of *"vorlegen"*, i.e. only with a subject and without an object, because I did not know this verb could be used in such an intransitive way. I have looked in the Duden and elsewhere, but I could not find this usage.

Therefore:

- Is the above sentence correctly constructed in German ?
- Instead, could/should we use the verb in a reflexive way, for instance *"Zum Zeitpunkt des letzten Komitees lagen **sich** noch keine aktuellen Werte für die Prognosen der Bank."* ?

Comment: Note the past tense of "vorlegen" would be "legten vor" - *vorlegen* is a seperable verb. - So it must be something else...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is fine. The verb there is "vorliegen", though, which is always intransitive.

Comment: Ach so! Danke vielmals!